# How to make a thread wait for a specific condition

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

There is a thread calculating prime numbers and adding them into a collection.

Now there are other Threads which will perform a `bool isPrime(long n)` method. This method will just look into the collection if it contains the number (n).

But the thread performing `isPrime(...)` needs to wait until:

- the number was added
- there is a number greater than n so I know n can't be prime.

And its only allowed to notify the thread in this cases. So I can't notify after every number added to the collection and check if its the number or higher.

Can you just give me some explanation about this waiting for conditions without busy waiting?

I just know that I can make threads wait on objects and other threads can notify them but i just cant get my head around this behavior, maybe I just think in a wrong way.

Comment: Any feedback on the answers you received?

Answer (score 4):

This really depends on your overall design.

A simple solution would work like this:

- you have 1 thread prime-generator and n threads prime-testers
- initially all prime-testers call `wait()`
- every time prime-generator adds a new prime, it notifies **all** prime-testers
- each testers checks if **its** number (or a **larger** one) is already in, if the tester either found its number, or knows "not in". If not, it calls `wait()` again.

The great advantage of that solution: the prime-generator doesn't need to know about how many prime-testers exist. It just notifies all threads waiting on a common monitor.

Alternatively, the prime-generator could know exactly which prime-testers exist, and also, what number they are responsible for. So instead of waking up all testers, it would notify only that one that needs to know.

Please understand: you only gave some vague requirements, without any code. Thus you receive a somehow vague answer, without any code. My answer is meant as inspiration to guide your next steps in your homework.

And just for the record: if you want to go for really large prime numbers, then using a list is a bad choice. Assume your list contains 1 million primes. The cost for calling `contains()` will grow linear with the number of entries. So rather use a collection that allows for quick finding of elements (some sort of set/tree), but also for quick access to the currently "last" (largest) number in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea from the answer by @GhostCat turned into code:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class PrimeThreading {
    // All prime numbers found so far.
    private static final Set<Long> primes = new HashSet<>();
    // Last number checked by the generator.
    private static long numbersChecked = 0L;
    // The lock object.
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    private static class PrimeGenerator implements Runnable {
        private final long maxNumber = Long.MAX_VALUE;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Generate all prime numbers from 2 to maxNumber
            for (long n = 2; n < maxNumber; n++) {
                // Naively test if n is prime.
                boolean isPrime = true;
                for (long i = 2; i * i < n; i++) {
                    if (n % i == 0) {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                synchronized (lock) {
                    if (isPrime) {
                        primes.add(n);
                    }
                    numbersChecked = n;
                    // Notify waiting threads
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(long x) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // Wait until number checked is greater than x
            while (x > numbersChecked) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return primes.contains(x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new PrimeGenerator());
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        System.out.println(isPrime(15_485_863));
    }
}
```